# putting the content right in the middle between two span

Tags: html, css

like stackoverflow voting arrows and points, I've made something similar but the point inside my two arrows aren't in the middle that it's so ugly. How do I correct this?

```html
<td class="vert-align">
  <div>
    <a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote">
    <span style="font-size:1.5em;" <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
    </span></a><br>
    <h4 id="vote_count_{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.get_vote_count }}</h4>     <br>
    <a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote">
    <span style="font-size:1.5em;" <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></span></a>
  </div>
</td>
```

Edit

So I have this

```
 <td class="vert-align">
        <div>
<a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote">
 <span style="font-size:1.5em;"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
 </span></a><br>

<h4 id="vote_count_{{ post.slug }}" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;">{{ post.get_vote_count }}</h4>
 <br>

<a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote">
<span style="font-size:1.5em;" <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></span></a>
        </div>
        </td>
```

I did this

```
    #vote_count_{{ post.slug }}{
      font-size: 34px;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 40px;
      margin: 0;
    }
    table{
      text-align: center;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

then I get nothing. 
IF I put h4 instead of id, then it works but I have other h4
```

Comment: Make a demo with what you have first please

Comment: As the highlighter tells you, your HTML is invalid. `<span style="font-size:1.5em;"` is missing a closing `>` (two times).

Comment: close your span tag '>'

Comment: Just create a snippet or fiddle so we could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```css
h4{
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}
table{
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>

<td class="vert-align">
        <div>
<a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote">
 <span style="font-size:2em;" <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
 </span></a>

<h4 id="vote_count_{{ post.slug }}">4</h4>    

<a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote">
<span style="font-size:2em;" <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></span></a>
        </div>
        </td>
 </table>
```

**EDIT**

**If you are looking for a stackoverflow like voting system, follow this**

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ckvork03/3/)**

```js
$('.vote.up').click(function () {
  $('span.upvote').toggleClass('on');
});

$('.vote.down').click(function () {
  $('span.downvote').toggleClass('on');
});
```

```css
h4.vote-count{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}
table{
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
span.upvote{
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqN2k.png');
  background-position: 0 -25px;
}
span.downvote{
  background : url('http://i.imgur.com/DdDtGWS.png');
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-position: 0 0px;
}

span.upvote.on {
  background-position: 0 2px;
}
span.downvote.on {
  background-position: 0 -30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

<td class="vert-align">
        <div>
<a href="#" class="vote up">
 <span class="upvote" style="font-size:1.5em;"
 </span></a>

<h4 class="vote-count" id="vote_count_{{ post.slug }}">4</h4>    

<a href="#"  class="vote down">
 <span class="downvote" style="font-size:1.5em;"
 </span></a>
        </div>
        </td>
 </table>
```

Comment: Is this answer helped you Kim ?

Comment: I have another h4 so it changed every h4,but beside that yeah

Comment: I'm getting a problem with your answer, I tried #"vote_count_{{ post.slug }}"{bunch of css }

Comment: then I don't get anything

Comment: Can I have a working demo ? That way I can help you better :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100349/discussion-between-kim-kimm-and-jinu-kurian).

Comment: do you want me to just post here?

Comment: can we chat through discussion?

Comment: same for others, it shows of as the point being close to upper arrow

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a fiddle, I can straight away see that you've not closed your span tag, please readjust as follows:

```
<td class="vert-align">
    <div>
        <a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote">
            <span style="font-size:1.5em;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></span>
        </a>
        <br>
        <h4 id="vote_count_{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.get_vote_count }}</h4>
        <br>
        <a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote">
            <span style="font-size:1.5em;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Here's a revised fiddle with Font Awesome added: https://jsfiddle.net/h5xhsaLe/3/

You can also reduce the padding above and below the `<h4>` element with CSS:

```
h4 {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but why is it still ugly....there's too much space between arrows and the point...I want it to be displayed stack overflow

Comment: Which part exactly are you referring to as "ugly"? Just try experimenting with the padding / margins, etc. The `<h4>` element for example has margin above and below it by default according to the browser, so try overriding this with CSS: `h4 { margin: 5px 0; }`

Comment: I just realized if I close span I get like a little glitch next to up arrow

Comment: I get _ next to up arrow

Comment: @kimkimm, try this updated fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/h5xhsaLe/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/h5xhsaLe/2/). There was an extra space which cause the anchor element to put an underline in..

Comment: why is mine still so ugly, I posted the pic here http://imgur.com/L0JZOhx compared to SO it;s so ugly. If I put that margin thing you did for css, the point goes off so I took it off

Comment: @kimkimm, It looks as though there's 2 parts to your question. One is getting the buttons and button layout to work (which a few people including myself have answered), the other is styling it so it looks prettier.

Answer (score 0):

Try Giving margin like this.

```
<h4 id="vote_count_{{ post.slug }}" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;">{{ post.get_vote_count }}</h4>
```

Comment: Why inline styling? Much better to put it in an external CSS file in my opinion...